# How can I programmatically validate that an user has uploaded an image in CCK?

Tags: 6, entities

I have an image field defined using CCK.  I need to detect or validate that the image has been uploaded.  Is it possible?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().Define your own module and in your module try the following code

```
function yourModuleName_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'yourModuleName_FORM_ID_validate';
}

//your validation function
function yourModuleName_FORM_ID_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($_FILES['files']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['machine_name_of_the_cck_field'])) {
    // File uploaded
  }
  else {
    //File not uploaded
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even easier, you can do it with Rules on condition "Field xx has changed".

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the CCK image field as a required field and the form won't validate unless the user uploads an image.